# Add mask in an input text field in Symfony 3.1.1 form

Tags: php, symfony, mask

**Solution:**

Solved it! Instead of installing the plugin via the composer, I manually copied and pasted the jquery-mask js file content and imported it. :)

**Question:**

I need to add a mask into a text field of a Symfony 3.1.1 form. This is the form I am rendering:

```
{# E-mail // Usuario #}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5  col-md-offset-1">
        E-mail<span style="color: #217db1;">*</span></br>
        {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'formularioRegistro'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    {# CPF #}
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        CPF (somente números)<span style="color: #217db1;">*</span></br>
        {{ form_widget(form.cpf, { 'attr': {'class': 'formularioRegistro'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.cpf) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the mask for the CPF field, which should have the following format: "_ _ _ . _ _ _ . _ _ _ - _ _". I mean, "3 digits **point** 3 digits **point** 3 digits **slash** 2 digits".

I tried to use javascript referencing the input id, but had no success.

Comment: Have you tried it with an placeholder? `'attr' : {'class': 'formularioRegistrio', 'placeholder': '___.___.___.__'} })` or better to add one in the FormBuilder Type file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this jquery plugin.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

In the Form:

```
$builder->add(
            'property', TextType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => ['data-mask' => '000.000.000-00']
            'placeholder' => '_ _ _ . _ _ _ . _ _ _ - _ _'
        ));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one. But it requires Symfony 2.8, I am using the 3.1 version.
This is the message I get when try to install via composer:
"it/input-mask-bundle 1.1.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.8"

Comment: Don't use the bundle, is out of date, include only the js file in your scripts and use like any other jquery plugin to use with all inputs using "data-mask"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a placeholder? if so, if your form class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

$builder->add('property', TextType::class, array(
    'required'    => false,
    'placeholder' => '_ _ _ . _ _ _ . _ _ _ - _ _'
));
```

Comment: The problem with the placeholder attribute is, it will no longer be visible once the user starts typing and doesn't enforce a given format (Though your backend validation after should do this anyways to be sure). The placeholder option could be enough based on the use-case but maybe something more sophisticated like https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ (the example with placeholder option) is what he is looking for

Comment: Joe is right on this one, a placeholder will not be sufficient. But I trie to install this bundle and it requires Symfony 2.8, I am using the 3.1 version.